# Ошибка несовместимости типов (SQLSTATE 42P08)

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, golang

Есть условная таблица `titles`:

```
   Column          |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |                   Default
-------------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------
id                 | integer                |           | not null | nextval('indexing_results_id_seq'::regclass)
document_id        | integer                |           |          |
title              | character varying(255) |           | not null |
normalized_title   | tsvector               |           | not null |
```

В неё я добавляю новую строку:

```
documentId := 1
title := "Some title"

_, err = connect.Query(currentContext,
    "INSERT INTO titles (document_id, title, normalized_title) VALUES ($1, $2, to_tsvector($2))",
    &documentId, &title) //передаём title один раз, но используем его в запросе дважды
```

Но в ответ получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR: inconsistent types deduced for parameter $2 (SQLSTATE 42P08)
```

По какой-то причине PostgreSQL не нравится параметр под номером 2 (он дважды используется в запросе).

---

Если указать тип (хотя бы в одном из мест), то новая строка добавляется нормально и ошибка не выводится:

```
_, err = connect.Query(currentContext,
    "INSERT INTO titles (document_id, title, normalized_title) VALUES ($1, $2::varchar(255), to_tsvector($2))",
    &documentId, &title) //указали приведение типа
```

Также помогает передать одну и ту же переменную `title` 2 раза:

```
_, err = connect.Query(currentContext,
    "INSERT INTO titles (document_id, title, normalized_title) VALUES ($1, $2, to_tsvector($3))",
     &documentId, &title, &title) //вместо двух переменных передаём три
```

Если не заполнить одно из полей, то тоже всё ок:

```
_, err = connect.Query(currentContext,
    "INSERT INTO titles (document_id, title, normalized_title) VALUES ($1, '', to_tsvector($2))",
    &documentId, &title) //пропустили поле title
```

---

Я никак не могу понять, почему я не могу использовать переменную `title` в запросе 2 или более раз (`$1, $2, $2`) без приведения типов? И почему приведение типов помогает избавиться от этой ошибки? В коде я уже всё пересмотрел по несколько раз, но так и не могу выяснить, почему так происходит.

P.S. Если это важно, для работы с PostgreSQL (12 версии) я использую драйвер [pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx).

Comment: Это вполне нормальная ситуация.  Строчный литерал может неявно конвертироваться во множество типов, и когда случается конфликт, БД требуется помощь от программиста.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, я впервые сталкиваюсь с такой ситуацией. Что ж, буду указывать явное приведение типов при множественном использовании переменной в запросе.

Comment: У Вас два использования значения, причём требуются РАЗНЫЕ типы данных. VARCHAR(255) для `title` и TEXT для аргумента `to_tsvector()`. А значение - одно! которое не может быть одновременно двух типов. Отсюда и конфликт, приводящий к ошибке.

Comment: @Akina Да, но мы же в обоих случаях передаём на вход строку. Можно сделать приведение типа к VARCHAR(255) не у `title`, а в аргументе функции `to_tsvecor()`: `... VALUES  ($1, $2, to_tsvector($2::varchar(255)))` и ошибки не будет, даже несмотря на то, что там требуется не VARCHAR(255), а TEXT.

Comment: Два преобразования. `VARCHAR(255) => TEXT` и `VARCHAR(255) <= TEXT`. Какое из них возможно всегда, а какое нет? Преобразование в `VARCHAR(255)` помогает для любого аргумента - а в `TEXT`? Golang не знает ни про `VARCHAR(255)`, ни про `TEXT` - так что же он передаёт? Найди ответы на все эти вопросы (и докажи себе, что прав) - и остальные сами собой отпадут.

Comment: @Akina Да, пожалуй вы правы. Оформите пожалуйста ваш комментарий как ответ и я приму его. Так будет легче найти информацию мне и другим людям, которые потом столкнутся с этим же вопросом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как написал [Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina) в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1094667/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2-sqlstate-42p08#comment1885044_1094667) к этому вопросу, для разных полей требуются разные значения:

- для поля `title` - `varying(255)`
- для функции `to_tsvector()` - `text`

Соответственно, нам нужно указывать приведение типов. Вот итоговое решение:

```
_, err = connect.Query(currentContext,
    "INSERT INTO titles (document_id, title, normalized_title) VALUES ($1, $2::varchar(255), to_tsvector($2::text))",
    &documentId, &title)
```